# Redirect a post to it's root category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My blog posts can be in multiple categories, so they're accessable from

mywebsite.com/root-category/children-category-A/blog-post

and

mywebsite.com/root-category/children-category-B/blog-post

I need a redirect rule (in htaccess or with wp_redirect() function) which redirects the blog posts always to

mywebsite.com/root-category/blog-post

**My attempt**

```
$category_parent_check = get_the_category(); 
$category_parent_id = $category_parent_check[0]->category_parent;
if ( $category_parent_id != 0 ) {
    $category_parent = get_term( $category_parent_id, 'category' );
    $css_slug = $category_parent->slug;
} else {
    $css_slug = $category_parent_check[0]->slug;
}

if ($css_slug == "root-category") {
  wp_redirect(get_site_url() . "/root-category" . wp_make_link_relative( get_page_link())); exit;
}
```

I did this inside my single.php, but I didn't think about that `$css_slug == "root-category"` will always be true and an endless redirection is the result.

So how do I achieve that?

**EDIT**

my htaccess

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 </Files>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^root-category/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a full redirect with `R` flag, it is much easier to do that in a single redirect rule in your main .htaccess **just below** `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(root-category)/[^/]+/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# remaining rules go below this line
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: A htaccess solution would be good. This is almost working. It redirects me to mywebsite.com/blog-post but it should be mywebsite.com/root-category/blog-post. See my edited question to take a look at my htaccess. I have tried /root-category/$1/$2 to see if this helps. the url after that was mywebsite.com/root-category/blog-post// and the page redirected me too often

Comment: Problem is that you didn't copy rule exactly as shown here. I used `RewriteRule ^(root-category)/[^/]+/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]` but you have it as `RewriteRule ^root-category/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]` (no brackets around `root-category`). Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Now it works, it redirects me to mywebsite.com/root-category/blog-post just how I want it. But I get too many redirects, why? Is it because of the htaccess rule or some conflict with wordpress?

Comment: problem solved, had to add remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical'); to the functions.php. Thank you, working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

please use below code in your `function.php` so i think it will remove child category from permalink.

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'my_filter_post_link' );

function my_get_all_child_categories( $category_id ) {

  $subcategories = array();

  $category = get_category( $category_id );
  if ( $category->parent ) {
    $subcategories[] = $category->slug . '/';
    $results = my_get_all_child_categories( $category->parent );
    $subcategories = array_merge( $subcategories, $results );
  }

  return $subcategories;
}

function my_filter_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

  if ( 'post' != get_post_type( $post ) )
    return $permalink;

  switch ( $post->post_type ) {
    case 'post':

      $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
      $subcategories = array();

      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $results = my_get_all_child_categories( $category->term_id );
        $subcategories = array_merge( $subcategories, $results );
      }

      $permalink = str_replace( $subcategories, '', $permalink );

      break;
  }

  return $permalink;
}
```

Comment: Please `print_r($subcategories);exit;` after `$subcategories` variable and let me know what result you get

Answer (score 0):

From WordPress admin you can change your blog single Page url :

**Go to**

```
Settings >> Permalinks
```

Select **Custom Structure** radio and enter this rewrite rule in text box

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I did checked with blog post on localhost and its working fine.